# Is there any way to force a "random" MSI to do a single user install?

Tags: windows-installer

I've got an MSI for an application that automatically installs for every user in the computer. I want it to install the application for just the current user. Is there any way to force this upon running the MSI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you can try setting the property "ALLUSERS"
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367559(VS.85).aspx

If you are installing the package on Win7 this article could also be useful:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows_installer_team/archive/2009/09/02/authoring-a-single-package-for-per-user-or-per-machine-installation-context-in-windows-7.aspx

Comment: I used ALLUSERS=2 and MSIINTSTALLPERUSER=1. Thanks loads

Answer (score 3):

msiexec /ju command line switch? [Msiexec (command-line options)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367988(v=vs.85).aspx)

Note, this performs a kind of 'lazy' installation, nothing is installed immediately. Instead it adds a shortcut to the users desktop, when this is run the application then installs for the current user only.

Comment: I used msiexec /ju SomeMSIName on Windows 7 SP1 and it did the job for me.